# Refreshing a cached xml file based on modified date that is loaded via http

Tags: c#, xml, caching, linq-to-xml

I have some data stored in an xml file that I want to avoid having to load and parse on every request. The file can be modified at any time directly. It is consumed by an asp.net mvc application over http (via `XDocument.Load`). I'm thinking of storing the file using asp.net caching but need the cache to refresh when the xml file is updated.

**Can I find out the last modified date of a file that is stored on a remote server?**

The file is actually stored inside a virtual directory that is probably going to be on the same server as the mvc application but I can't rely on that.

**If not, is there another mechanism by which I can know whether to use the cached version or to reload the actual file?**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be able to utilize the `IF-MODIFIED-SINCE` http header. [Se other SO question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998791/if-modified-since-vs-if-none-match) or the [w3c definition here.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)